# XCTest VC Hierarchy without XCUITest?

Tags: unit-testing, xctest, xcuitest

I want to test a ViewController hierarchy without using XCUITests, because they take a huge ton longer than plain old XCTests.

I've had some success but I can't seem to create a ViewController hierarchy more than one level deep.

Here's a test case demonstrating the issue:

```
class VCHierarchyTests: XCTestCase {

    func test_CanMakeViewControllerHierarchy() {

          let baseVC = UIViewController()
          let vcToPresent = UIViewController()
          let vcOnTopOfThat = UIViewController()
          let vcOnTopOfThatOnTopOfThat = UIViewController()
          newKeyWindowWith(root: baseVC)
          baseVC.present(vcToPresent, animated: false)
          vcToPresent.present(vcOnTopOfThat, animated: false)
          vcOnTopOfThat.present(vcOnTopOfThatOnTopOfThat, animated: false)

          //this passes:
          XCTAssertNotNil(baseVC.presentedViewController)
          //this fails:
          XCTAssertNotNil(vcToPresent.presentedViewController)
          //this fails:
          XCTAssertNotNil(vcOnTopOfThat.presentedViewController)
    }

    private func newKeyWindowWith(root viewController: UIViewController){
           let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
           window.makeKeyAndVisible()
           window.rootViewController = viewController
    }
}
```

Is there a way to construct ViewController hierarchies without XCUITest?

Answer (score 1):

Try `PresentationVerifier` from [ViewControllerPresentationSpy](https://github.com/jonreid/ViewControllerPresentationSpy) to unit test how view controllers are presented.

It's designed to intercept a single `present()` call, not several of them. If your use case falls outside what it does, please file an Issue.